# Azure: How to manage development and production websites

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have been using Azure for some time for some different website I have been working on. Using visual Studio to do the publish and Azure holds the website and the sql. My question is this: How do I manage to publish to the development site and the production site? I have looked around on the web and have not found what I have been looking for so far.
If I choose the publish profile for my production site, and publish via visual studio, how do I control that the website uses the correct production db? In the web.config of the site is currently the connectionstring for the development sql db.
I dont want to sit and change the connection string every time I want to publish to the production site. There must be an easier way to do this?
I imagine that when I sattisfied with the looks of the website on the development site, I will move it to the production site. But how is this handled?
Hope you can help or send me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Connection Strings in the Azure Portal, specify the production connection string in the production site configuration and the dev connection string in the dev site configuration.

> these connection strings are injected into your .NET configuration connectionStrings settings at runtime, overriding existing entries where the key equals the linked database name.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure/